# how to print a list like a string?

Tags: python, list, printing

I am trying to print a list like a string:

```
    list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

the output I want it to be;

```
    abcdef
```

Comment: Use '' ".join(list)...

Comment: You should try something yourself and if then you are facing problem to do so you can come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `join()` method, in python, `join()` returns a string in which the string elements of sequence have been joined by `str` separator.

```
str = ''
sequence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
print str.join(sequence)
```

You can pass any  `list` or `tuple` as `sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print it, you can make use of the `end` parameter of `print`. It defaults to "\n" and is what is printed at the end of the string passed to it:

```
for i in list:
    print(i, end="")
```

If you actually want the string, you can just add them together(not in all python versions):

```
string=""
for i in list:
    sting+=i
```

If you know how many items are in your list:

```
string=list[0]+list[1]+list[2]+list[3]+list[4]
```

or:

```
print(list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4], sep="")
```

(sep is what is printed between each string, defaults to `" "`, However the two above are quite messy.

Comment: These are all alternatives to SpiXel's answer, which is also perfectly valid, and is easier to use.