# How to display a list in string format in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a hashtag generation randomizer that can be used for Instagram using Python.

What I want to print like

```
#picture #art #gallery #goodart #sky #fashion
```

but actually the following code was printed.

```
['#picture', '#art', '#gallery', '#goodart', '#sky', '#fasion']
```

How can I print like this?

```
#picture #art #gallery #goodart #sky #fashion
```

My code is below.

```
import random

tag1 = ["#photo", "#art", "#picture"]

tag1_list = random.sample(tag1, 2)

tag2 = ["#artlover", "#goodart", "#gallery"]

tag2_list = random.sample(tag2, 2)

tag3 = ["#beautiful", "#fasion", "#sky"]

tag3_list = random.sample(tag3, 2)

all_tags = tag1_list + tag2_list + tag3_list

print(all_tags)
```

Comment: `print(" ".join(tag1))`?

Comment: Try unpacking: `print(*all_tags)`

Comment: [how to print a list like a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49465497/15032126)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `all_tags` and print every tag one by one. Using `end=" "` as parameter for the `print()` function for having a whitespace at the end of every print instead of a newline

```
for tag in all_tags:
    print(tag, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `join` the list with a delimiter of `' '`:

```py
print(' '.join(all_tags))
```